Unity crisp graphics and 1pixel width gaps with different screen resolutions
I am trying to make a puzzle game but I wonder how to get crisp graphics.
For example how does a game like “blocks blast” (which is written in unity) achieve its graphics, are they using sprites or using vector graphics somehow?
In am currently using qt/qml which uses vector graphics and I tried to achieve the same in unity but scaling does not give me perfectly crisp graphics

if its what i think it is (and as no pictures or otherwise confirmation) its the tetris like game? probably a tilemap
